# How to use Auth0 with Firestore and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, auth0

I have a NextJS and React project where I use Auth0 as login.
I also use Firestore as database-storage and want to use Auth0 as authentication with Firestore.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a lot articles about this subject. Pasting some I found:

[one](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/authenticate-firebase-with-auth0/), [two](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-firebase-and-angular-with-auth0-part-1/), [three](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-firebase-and-angular-with-auth0-part-2/), [four](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-real-time-apps-with-firebase-and-firestore/), [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502036/is-possible-to-integrate-auth0-to-firebase-like-this-way), [six](https://github.com/auth0-blog/firestore-web-chat).

You should be able to figure it out. At least how to start, than you can come back with code samples.

I hope it will help!